# React state is not updating on PouchDB get details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pouchdb

I was trying to use PouchDb in react.

I written the code to get the data from PouchDb database. But the state was not updating.

here my code.

```
  getInitialState:function() {
    return {
            NAME: ""
     };
  },
  GetData: function () {

    var deviceId = localStorage.getItem("deviceId");    
    return db.get(deviceId);    
  },
    getPouchData:function(){

      var $self = this;

      $self.GetData().then(function(doc){

          var response = JSON.parse(doc.data);             

          $self.state.NAME = response.NAME;          

      });
    },  
  componentWillMount: function () {
      this.getPouchData();    
  },
```

Comment: You cannot mutate the state like that. You have to use `$self.setState({NAME: response.NAME})` instead of `$self.state.NAME = response.NAME;`

Comment: I tried this also not updating the state. In render function I got only Initialized value only